# Attribute warnings for PyTorch classes in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, pytorch

I'm getting warnings for certain instructions.

Example 1:

Code:

```
input_a = Variable(torch.stack(a1, dim=0), requires_grad=False).to(self.device)
```

Warnings:

> Unexpected argument(s)
>
> Possible callees:
>
> object(self: object)
>
> object.__new__(cls: object)
>
> Unresolved attribute reference 'to' for class 'Variable'

Example 2:

Code:

```
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=self.lr, betas=(0.9, 0.999), eps=1e-8)
...
print('%d minutes: epoch %d loss = %.3f, learning rate: %.4f'
              % ((time.time() - start_time) // 60, epoch + 1, avg_loss, optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr']))
```

Warning:

> Type 'Adam' doesn't gave expected attribute 'param_groups'

What do they mean and how should I rewrite my code to remove them?

Comment: As you're using `Variable`, I assume you're using an older version of pytorch (<1.0). You might be facing an issue where in previous pytorch versions, IDEs could not detect all of `torch`'s functionality correctly. See this issue https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/7318 in the pytorch github. That issue was fixed in pytorch 1.0.1

Comment: How can I check, which pytorch version I'm using? Going to Settings->Project->Project Interpreter only shows torch (1.2.0), not 'pytorch'. Or is that it? Then I'm using version higher than 1.